# Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve

Tags: angular

Estoy aprendiendo angular, y en el día de ayer hice un proyecto bastante simple donde recorría los datos de un array con un `*ngfor` y los mostraba en una tabla.
hoy al momento de querer levantar mi servidor de desarrollo me muestra el siguiente error:

> Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
> 'C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\proyectosAngular\app-empleados' in >C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\proyectosAngular\app-empleados'

Verifique que la ruta que se muestra en consola sea la correcta, pero igualmente sigue mostrando ese mismo error.

En el navegador muestra el siguiente error:

```
Cannot GET /
```

Angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "app-empleados": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/app-empleados",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
            ""],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "app-empleados:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "app-empleados:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app-empleados:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "app-empleados"
}
```

Comment: podrías compartir el código de la vista el componente y rutas que usas...si generas un nuevo proyecto también te da ese error?

Answer (score -1):

Para poder utilizar el comando de angular CLI, serve este comando levanta la aplicación en un servidor, para poder usar este comando debes asegurarte de estar en la ruta adecuada por ejemplo:

mi-proyecto/angularAPP

debes primero acceder a angularAPP con el comando cd angularAPP y luego ejecutar el comando ng serve.